# unable to show sql result in a popup modal window

Tags: php, javascript, css, popup, modalpopupextender

I have a css modal window. which i want to display the sql result. When i click on a link. after the link is clicked, it gets the id from `<a href="index.php?idi='.$id.'">` and selects the data from database and show in the popup, this where i have place the code to view on popup `index.php`. but this is not working, I need to know what is missing or what has to be added, thank you

```
if (isset($_GET['idi'])) {
    $pop_id = $_GET['idi'];
    $popList="";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$pop_id' LIMIT 1");
    if($sql === false) {
        var_dump(mysql_error()); 
    }
else {
    print_r(mysql_num_rows($sql));
}
$popCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($popCount == 1)  {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){


             $exp = $row["expiry"];
             $com = $row["comments"];
             $term = $row["terms"];
             $qid = $row["id"];
             $pname = $row["product_name"];
             $rs = $row["price"];
             $detail = $row ["details"];

             $popList .= '<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="tc_form"></a>
        <div class="popup">
             <h2>Product Offer</h2>
                         <p></p>
            <div>
            <label for="pass">Price <?php echo $rs; ?></label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="firstname">Expiry Date</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="lastname">Details</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lastname">Conditions</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lastname">Terms & Conditions</label>
            </div>
            </div>';
    }
} else {
    echo "That item does not exist.";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think you have missing the `echo` statement for listing saved in `$popList` variable. Add following code in to bottom of your code

```
echo $popList;
```

Comment: in my coding i have placed the echo $popList;
but it does not popup